# Syntax error: Dynamic SQL in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am pretty new to SQL Server that might be the reason I am facing this syntax error.

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBaseVoterIndex  
    @order_col NVARCHAR(100) ,  
    @order_dir NVARCHAR(20) ,  
    @offset ITN,  
    @limit INT 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1, home_address_city FROM dbo.base_voter'  
               +' WITH(NOLOCK)'  
               +' ORDER BY @OC @OD'  
               +' OFFSET @OF ROWS'  
               +' FETCH NEXT @LIM ROWS ONLY'  

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,  
               N'@OC nvarchar(191),@OD nvarchar(10),@OF int,@LIM int',  
               @OC @order_col, @OD @order_dir, @OF @offset, @LIM @limit  
END
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spBaseVoterIndex, Line 18 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near '@order_col'.

What am I doing wrong here. Also, is this the best way to perform dynamic SQL or is there any other optimize way?

Printing `@SQL` results in

```
SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1, home_address_city 
FROM dbo.base_voter WITH(NOLOCK) 
ORDER BY @OC @OD 
OFFSET @OF ROWS 
FETCH NEXT @LIM ROWS ONLY
```

## Update

I have this code working

```
SELECT id,
name_voter,
home_street_address_1,
home_address_city
FROM dbo.base_voter
WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
order by name_voter asc
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

All I want to make it dynamic and among them these `name_voter asc` and offset value `0` and limit value `50` these are 4 params which I want to make dynamic.

There are 100M rows of data so performance is also important.

Comment: Your single quote is on first line only on Execute part

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong is not printing and inspecting `@sql`. That's your first stop.

Comment: @slon sorry, I don't get it

Comment: See the color of last two lines of code right before End

Comment: @nick printing @sql shows `SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1, home_address_city FROM dbo.base_voter WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY @OC @OD OFFSET @OF ROWS FETCH NEXT @LIM ROWS ONLY`

Comment: I will edit your question and put it in - in future please do it that way as then all the info is in the question.

Comment: OK it looks like there are some syntax errors in your SQL but there are also errors in your `sp_executesql ` as already pointed out.

Comment: @slon I have updated 2nd line of execute with 
`N'@OC @order_col,@OD @order_dir,@OF @offset,@LIM @limit'`. Although, it build the stored procedure. However, If i try to execute spBaseVoterIndex 'name_voter', 'asc', 0, 50 it shows error 
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near '@OD'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 22
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.`

Comment: If you check your code around the `@order_col` identifier as mentioned in the error, you'll see there is a missing comma. But I don't think that will work anyway - I don't think you can parameterise it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work that way - you can't parameterise ASC like that. You need to literally concatenate the strings.

It's a good idea to add some string sanitation to stop SQL injection

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBaseVoterIndex  
    @order_col NVARCHAR(100) ,  
    @descending INT,  
    @offset INT,  
    @limit INT 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
BEGIN

   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
   DECLARE @OD varchar(4) = 'ASC'

   -- Default is ascending. Pass in 1 to order descending
   IF @descending = 1 THEN SET @OD='DESC'

   -- If the order column is not valid, exit
   -- You need to put a list of valid columns in here
   IF @order_col NOT IN ('column1','column2','column3') RETURN


   -- Finally build and run the SQL
    SET @sql = 'SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1, home_address_city'
               +' FROM dbo.base_voter'  
               +' WITH(NOLOCK)'  
               +' ORDER BY ' + @order_col + ' ' + @OD + ' '
               +' OFFSET ' + CAST(@offset AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ROWS'  
               +' FETCH NEXT ' + CAST(@limit AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ROWS ONLY'  

EXEC(@sql)

END
```

With regards to performance, there are two parts to this:

1. Make sure you have the correct indexes
2. This kind of dynamic 'kitchen sink' SQL can always suffer from performance issues regardless because you can't pre-compile a query plan. It will never suffer from parameter sniffing though.

Comment: Won't that be prone to sql injection?

Comment: Most definitely

Comment: could you suggest how can I do with case statement

Comment: I have just updated the question please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a comma between @OC and @OD in the line 
    +' ORDER BY @OC @OD'

Did you also notice that the size of your paramaters changes between the Procedure definition and the dynamic SQL definition?

You can test by replacing the dynamic SQL parameters with the actual ones and simply printing the final string and then running that.

Other than making sure that you are aware of the possible issues with using NOLOCK (dirty reads, phantom reads, duplicated data), your usage looks valid.

Comment: This is raw query which is working, `SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1, home_address_city FROM dbo.base_voter WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY name_voter asc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ONLY` And what you are saying is i should put comma between name_voter and asc. I don't think that makes sense.

Comment: OK it's not going to work that way. You need to use dynamic SQL, which means you concatenate the variables into a string. You don't pass them into `sp_executesql` as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBaseVoterIndex  
    @order_col NVARCHAR(100) ,  
    @order_dir NVARCHAR(20) ,  
    @offset INT,  
    @limit INT 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1, home_address_city FROM dbo.base_voter'  
               +' WITH(NOLOCK)'  
               +' ORDER BY @OC @OD'  
               +' OFFSET @OF ROWS'  
               +' FETCH NEXT @LIM ROWS ONLY'  

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,  
               N'@OC nvarchar(100),@OD nvarchar(20),@OF int,@LIM int',  
               @OC=@order_col, @OD=@order_dir, @OF=@offset, @LIM=@limit  
END
```

Comment: Well, this is executed without any error. But when I try to execute `spBaseVoterIndex 'name_voter','asc',0,50` It throws error
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near '@OD'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 21
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.`

Comment: Try adding a comma between `@OD` and `@OD` in the `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: This is raw query which is working,
`SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1, home_address_city 
FROM dbo.base_voter WITH(NOLOCK) 
ORDER BY name_voter asc 
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 50 ONLY`
And what you are saying is i should put comma between name_voter and asc. I don't think that makes sense.

Comment: I thought the `@OD` variable stood for another column. The query seems fine and should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the parameters to the variables for sp_executesql. (You've already declared it, but didn't assign it (forgot to use the equal sign).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBaseVoterIndex  
    @order_col NVARCHAR(191) ,  
    @order_dir NVARCHAR(10) ,  
    @offset INT,  
    @limit INT 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1, home_address_city FROM dbo.base_voter'  
            +' WITH(NOLOCK)'  
            +' ORDER BY @order_col @order_dir'  
            +' OFFSET @offset ROWS'  
            +' FETCH NEXT @limit ROWS ONLY' 

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'@order_col',@order_col)
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'@order_dir',@order_dir)
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'@offset',@offset)
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'@limit',@limit)

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

END
```

BTW, in a non-dynamic SQL, `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` accepts INT variables. So, you can for instance use it like this (directly) :

```
SELECT 
    id
,   name_voter
,   home_street_address_1
,   home_address_city 
FROM 
    dbo.base_voter
ORDER BY id
OFFSET @offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT @limit ROWS ONLY
```

But this will force you to use a fixed order by (which is not a real issue btw). If you need to make use of order by, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` method, something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    id
,   name_voter
,   home_street_address_1
,   home_address_city 
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @order_col + @order_dir) RN
FROM 
    base_voter
) D 
WHERE
    RN > @Offset
AND RN <= @Limit + @Offset
```

this will give you the same results of `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT`

Hope this will be helpful someday.

Comment: This returns error 
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near '@OD'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 31
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.`
When I execute`spBaseVoterIndex 'name_voter','asc',0,50`